# articles_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I am attempting to go through the guide and learn by making the simple blog. When trying to access the localhost is gives me the error in the title. I'm sure this is an easy fix, I'm just unable to see it at the moment. Thank you!

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article.params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'

  end

  private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

  def index
     @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: You are missing an end as part of the if in your create method

Answer (score 4):

## Indentation

If your text editor cannot automatically indent code, use another one!

If your text editor can indent code, please use it ;)

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article.params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'

    end

    private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

    def index
      @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

You can see that `def create` is the last method definition with the correct indentation, so the problem must come from here.

## Params

You define `article_params` method but call `article.params`. That is likely another problem.

## Private methods

Any method that is defined after `private` keyword is private. Not just `article_params` but also `show` and `index`, in your case. I guess the last two should be public (i.e. above `private` keyword).

Comment: the comment about methods after private fixed it. I see what you were saying there, that makes so much sense now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `end` word in your `create` action. That must work

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article.params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

  def index
     @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: with additional "end" I got a new error, "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: `article_params` instead of `article.params` i guess

Comment: Thank you VAD! That helped. been a long day for me, hate commiting typos, haha.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!